# trpc `useSubscription` doesn't get React state updates

Tags: reactjs, next.js, websocket, trpc.io

I'm building a Next.js app with trpc that requires real time comunication. It has been going well, especially since my `useSubscription` calls have only been updating state rather than reading it so far.

I have a ContextProvider with some state which uses a web socket subscription through the useSubscription method. The isue is, the onData method depends on the Provider's state, but it doesn't get updated, only ever getting the initial state passed into the useState function

```
function Component() {
    const [state, setState] = useState('initial')
    const triggerSocket = trpc.trigger.useMutation()

    trpc.socket.useSubscription({
        onData() {
            console.log(state) // initial
        }
    })

    return <button onClick={async () => {
        setState('updated')
        await triggerSocket.mutateAsync()
    }}>Click me</button>
}
```

Am I missing something? Is this a trpc bug or am I doing something wrong? Is there some way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by swapping my `useState`'s with `useRef`'s. That worked well enough for now, still, if anyone can get `useState` to work, feel free to leave an answer here